# Generating a personal id for each user

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there anyway I can generate a unique sequence number using c#.we are developing a website where we assign a personal id to each user at the time of registration... I need to generate a 14 digit string.

```
For eg.

AA 01 201 210 22

AA 02 201 210 22

.

.

AA 99 201 210 22

then it should start from

AB 01 201 210 22

AB 02 201 210 22 and so on...

Last 8 digits are current date...

Thanks....



private string ConvertDecString(int value)
       {
            string CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            string retVal = string.Empty;
            int remainder = 0;
            do
            {
                remainder = value % 26;
                retVal = CHARS.Substring(remainder, 1) + retVal;
                value = (value / 26) - 1;
            }
            while ((value + 1) > 0);
            return retVal;
        }


public string GetCurrentDate()
    {
        string todaydate = System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
        return todaydate;
    }

    private Random _random = new Random();

    public int RadomNum()
    {
        return _random.Next(10, 99);
    }

private string GetActualDate()
    {
        string Year = System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        string ActualDate1 = Year + GetProperMonth() + GetProperDay();
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(ActualDate1);
        string ActualDate = String.Format("{0:000 000 00}", n);
        return ActualDate;
    }

    private string GetProperMonth()
    {
        string Month = System.DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
        string MonthNo = "";

        if (Month == "1")
        {
            MonthNo = "01";
        }
        else if (Month == "2")
        {
            MonthNo = "02";
        }
        else if (Month == "3")
        {
            MonthNo = "03";
        }
        else if (Month == "4")
        {
            MonthNo = "04";
        }
        else if (Month == "5")
        {
            MonthNo = "05";
        }
        else if (Month == "6")
        {
            MonthNo = "06";
        }
        else if (Month == "7")
        {
            MonthNo = "07";
        }
        else if (Month == "8")
        {
            MonthNo = "08";
        }
        else if (Month == "9")
        {
            MonthNo = "09";
        }
        else
        {
            MonthNo = Month;
        }
        return MonthNo;
    }


    private string GetProperDay()
    {
        string Day = System.DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
        string DayNo = "";

        if (Day == "1")
        {
            DayNo = "01";
        }
        else if (Day == "2")
        {
            DayNo = "02";
        }
        else if (Day == "3")
        {
            DayNo = "03";
        }
        else if (Day == "4")
        {
            DayNo = "04";
        }
        else if (Day == "5")
        {
            DayNo = "05";
        }
        else if (Day == "6")
        {
            DayNo = "06";
        }
        else if (Day == "7")
        {
            DayNo = "07";
        }
        else if (Day == "8")
        {
            DayNo = "08";
        }
        else if (Day == "9")
        {
            DayNo = "09";
        }
        else
        {
            DayNo = Day;
        }
        return DayNo;
    }

    public string GeneratePatientNumber(string Alpha)
        {
            return ConvertDecString(Convert.ToInt16(Alpha)) + " " + RadomNum() + " " + GetActualDate();
        }

GeneratePatientNumber(string Alpha) - this method generates 12 digit personal id...
```

Comment: So what is your question? Do you want the community to provide the code?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a complex problem: it's a formatted string containing a date and an incremented counter.  What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried any methods so far?

Comment: i tried a code which gives me series like A then 2 digits random nos...n then date...

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have?

Comment: @jamieKeeling did you check my code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string GetPersonalId (int n)
{
    char letter1 = (char)('A' + ((n / 10 / 26 / 26) % 26));
    char letter2 = (char)('A' + ((n / 10 / 26) % 26));
    char digit1 = (char)('0' + ((n / 10) % 10));
    char digit2 = (char)('0' + ((n) % 10));

    string dateString = string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", DateTime.Today)
        .Insert(6, " ")
        .Insert(3, " ");

    return string.Format("{0}{1} {2}{3} {4}",
        letter1, letter2, digit1, digit2, dateString);
}

public GetNextSequenceForToday()
{
    SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand()
    query.CommandText =
       "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Users] " +
       "WHERE [Date] >= @today AND [Date] < @tomorrow";
    query.Parameters.Add("@today", DateTime.Today);
    query.Parameters.Add("@tomorrow", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));

    int count = Convert.ToInt32(query.ExecuteScalar());

    return count + 1;
}
```

Comment: it gives error saying can not implicitly convert type int to char at this line: char letter1 = 'A' + ((n / 10 / 26 / 26) % 26);

Comment: Ok. I've added type conversions.

Comment: thanks a lot mate....

but our requirement is after AA 99 it should start from AB 01 and so on....
and every day it begins from AA 01 for 1st registered user of that particular day..how to manage all this things...

thank you..

Comment: @punit This is a Q&A site, not a place to have people write code for you. Anthony provided a very reasonable basis for you to continue using and make it your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class IDGenerator
    {
        private int _firstLetter = 0;
        private int _secondLetter = 0;
        private int _firstDigitCounter = 90;
        private string _chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        public string NewID()
        {
            return twoLetters();
        }

        private string twoLetters()
        {
            _firstDigitCounter += 1;
            if (_firstDigitCounter == 99)
            {
                _firstDigitCounter = 0;
                _secondLetter += 1;
            }

            if (_secondLetter > _chars.Length)
            {
                _secondLetter = 0;
                _firstLetter += 1;
            }

            return _chars.Substring(_firstLetter, 1) + _chars.Substring(_secondLetter, 1) + " " + _firstDigitCounter.ToString("00") + " " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Insert(3, " ") + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM dd");
        }
    }
```

Comment: just reset the _firstDigitCounter, i just did that for testing

Comment: i want to generate a string depending on some reg id...i.e m gonna pass int as a parameter to the function....

Answer (score -1):

You can create an unique 32 char length string using the Guid class.

```
Guid g;
g = Guid.NewGuid();
Console.WriteLine(g);
Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid());
```

C&P from : http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx#Y330

Comment: From OP: 'I need to generate a 14 digit string'.